# How to change display mode of Facebook authentication screen using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-authentication

When I call Facebook authenticate the popup is opened, but some browser blocked popup, So I want show login page as page like in the stack overflow!

Comment: see my answer, browsers do not block it if you do it right, but we cannot tell you anything else without seeing your code.

Comment: I am using angular-social-login

Answer (score 0):

Browsers only block the popup if it´s not opened on user interaction. Make sure you do not try to open it in an asynchronous callback function. `FB.login` must be called in the click event.

Seems like this is a known issue of angular-social-login:

- https://github.com/heresy/angularjs-social-login/issues/24
- https://github.com/heresy/angularjs-social-login/issues/20
- https://github.com/heresy/angularjs-social-login/issues/4

Comment: I am using the dependency `angular-social-login`